# How do I get module from a path?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to get module name from a path

```
        $path =  Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: that  mean you want to module name from  url .Am right ?

Comment: yes. For example if I was on `customer/account` page I recieve `customer`.

Comment: have you check out  http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-get-controller-action-and-module-name-in-template-file/

Comment: That is just for current Module/action. I want to do this for a URL.

Comment: means,support at checkout page.. you have write  code which give customer/account url and you want to get `customer/accuount` urls'  Module name?... i Am right?

Comment: I use the `$path` mentioned before that gets me previews page url. I want to get that's page Model. for example if I get `http://localhost/index.php/order/....`   I recieve` order`.